# BASH - Tomar los números UID_MIN y UID_MAX

Tags: bash, shell

Estaba programando una actividad en la que, en uno de los apartados, se me pide darle a dos variables el valor de `UID_MIN` y `UID_MAX` del `/etc/login.defs`. Bien, intenté hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
min=$(grep UID /etc/login.defs | head -1 | cut -f2 -d:)
max=$(grep UID /etc/login.defs | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d:)
```

El resultado es, simplemente, un espacio en blanco. ¿Cómo poder llegar a asignar el valor de esas dos variables?

El fichero tiene el siguiente formato:

```
#
# Min/max values for automatic uid selection in useradd
#
UID_MIN           500
UID_MAX         60000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los pipes ( '|' ), se utilizan para redirigir la salida de un proceso a la entrada de otro. En tu caso deberías redirigir la salida de la impresión del archivo, que es precisamente lo que no estás haciendo.

**Editado:**

Código:

```
min=$(cat /etc/login.defs | grep UID_MIN | sed 's/\s\+/,/g' | cut -d "," -f 2)

max=$(cat /etc/login.defs | grep UID_MAX | sed 's/\s\+/,/g' | cut -d "," -f 2)
```

Comment: He intentado con el código que me has sugerido (pero con algunas modificaciones que yo escribí mal desde el principio, y solo consigo sacar el UID_MIN. No hay forma de conseguir el UID_MAX. De todas maneras, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Podrías mostrar cómo te quedó el código, por favor?

Comment: min=$(cat /etc/login.defs | grep UID_MIN | cut -f3 -d' '); para la variable max, aunque utilizo el mismo que en min (cambiando el MIN por MAX) me devuelve la linea entera

Comment: No podrías pasar el archivo? Para saber como es el formato y lo pueda testear en mi pc

Comment: formato del pedazo que me interesa añadido. No sé cómo añadir un archivo, ando nuevo por aqui

Comment: Ahí lo probé y me funcionó, lo que hace es eliminar todos esos espacios por una coma, de esa forma se facilita el cut

Comment: Perfecto, lo acabo de probar y ha hecho lo que necesitaba, no se me ocurría esa expresión regular del espacio. muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Genarito es correcta. Sin embargo, considero interesante sugerirte que uses `awk` para estas computaciones, pues te permite hacer lo mismo sin tantos *pipes*:

```
$ awk '$1=="UID_MIN" {print $2}' /etc/login.defs 
1000
```

O incluso:

```
$ variable="UID_MIN"
$ awk -v var="$variable" '$1==var {print $2}' /etc/login.defs 
1000
```

Esto se lee así: en las líneas en las que la primera columna tenga el texto "UID_MIN", escribe la segunda columna. `awk` entiende como columnas lo que está separado por tabuladores o espacios por defecto.

Para "UID_MAX" es equivalente.